# Made a mistake checking into TFS 2013. Best way to revert?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I did a checkin in Visual Studio (2013) and realized that one of the projects wasn't loaded.

I've since reloaded the project and want to redo the checkin.

What is the best option to do this?  I see a Rollback Entire Changeset option, but will that cause me to loose my code?  Do I just view that changeset, reload and then overwrite the files with a backup of the files that I did change?

Comment: Is there actually a problem? Do you have CI on your check in? It doesn't necessarily mean that there will be a problem. I would make the project load and make sure it compiles locally and then check the pending changes. If there are none, you should be ok.

Comment: There isn't a problem, I just wanted a full changeset.  If I loaded the project and checked in the pending changes now that the project is loaded, it will create another changeset - right?

Comment: Oh I see... see answer below!

Answer (score 4):

If you rollback your changeset you won't lose any changes, a rollback simply creates a new changeset. So when you perform a rollback, you will see pending changes which will effectively reverse the changeset, then you can review and check in as normal. If you do so and you aren't happy, you can rollback the rollback!